# What is a sink app (in Tizen)?

Tags: bluetooth, tizen, tizen-web-app

In the Tizen Bluetooth-API, there is the healthProfileHandler, which has the method

```
void registerSinkApplication(unsigned short dataType, DOMString name,
                             BluetoothHealthApplicationSuccessCallback successCallback, 
                             optional ErrorCallback? errorCallback);
```

in the description, it says `Registers an application for the Sink role`, but what does this mean exactly? What is the Sink role? I just don't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think a Sink Application is kind of listening application that you have to register. As you can see in the parametr of function are included *Callback names.

Take care!

Comment: Yes, but is it an app which is then called and runs everytime, the callback is invoked, or how does it exactly work?